# "Click here to Download" in German

Tags: translation

How would you say "Click here to Download" in German? Is this correct? It seems awkward.

> Klicken Sie hier zum Download

Comment: Früher galt es als schlechter Stil, "hier" zu verwenden. Druck die Seite aus und kein Mensch weiß, was "hier" ist. Ich würde also eher sagen: "Download german.pdf (1,2 MB)" oder "SuperShooterInstall.exe (942 MB) herunterladen".

Comment: Auch "klicken" sollte man eigentlich nicht zur Kennzeichnung eines Links verwenden, denn das setzt einen Benutzeragenten voraus, der mit einer Maus (oder vielleicht einem Trackball) gesteuert wird. Insofern ist "klicken" weder rückwärtskompatibel zu textbasierten/tastaturgesteuerten Browsern, noch zukunftssicher für Touchscreens (von Barrierefreiheit ganz zu schweigen).

Comment: @Veredomon: Und bei "Download german.pdf", ausgedruckt, weiß man was `hier` ist?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Wenn ich mit lynx surfe weiß ich auch, dass ich mit Tab zum Link navigieren kann und Leertaste drücken oder Enter, um das Runterladen auszulösen, auch wenn da `Klicken` steht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es hört sich wirklich ein bisschen komisch an. Besser hört es sich an, wenn man entweder [herunterladen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herunterladen) nimmt oder die eingedeutschte Variante [downloaden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/downloaden).

Man könnte also schreiben:

> Klicken Sie hier zum Herunterladen.
>
> Klicken Sie hier zum Downloaden.

oder etwas länger, aber schöner:

> Klicken Sie hier, um den Download zu starten.

oder

> Hier klicken, um herunterzuladen.
>
> Hier klicken, um zu downloaden.

Answer (score 1):

If the click redirects you to another page, where the actual download starts, you can use

> Hier zum Download